# Struts1 and ActionForm inheritance, mess of data

Tags: struts, struts-1

I have a problem using Struts1 ActionForm beans. Please, see a part of my struts-config:

```
<!-- RuleSearchForm is a sublass of RuleForm -->
    form-beans>
            <form-bean name="ruleForm" 
                type="forms.RuleForm">
            </form-bean>
            <form-bean name="ruleSearchForm" 
                type="forms.RuleSearchForm">
            </form-bean>
        </form-beans>
    <!-- Mappings -->
    <action path="/RuleList" 
            type="actions.RuleList"
            name="ruleSearchForm"
            scope="session"
            validate="false">
        <forward name="success" path="/html/view/RuleList.jsp"></forward>
    </action>
    <action path="/RuleCreate" 
            type="actions.RuleCreate" 
            name="ruleForm" 
            scope="request" 
            validate="false">
        <forward name="success" path="/html/view/CreateUpdateRule.jsp"></forward>
    </action>
```

And parts of my Actionform beans code:

```
public class RuleForm extends ActionForm {
    protected Integer   crid;       
    protected List levels;        
    /** Some other fileds go here */

    public Collection getLevels(){
        if(levels == null){
            levels = DAOClass.getLevels();
            Collections.reverse(levels);
        }
        return levels;
    }

    /** Other getters/setters go here */
}

public class RuleSearchForm extends RuleForm{

    /**
     * Avoid filter reset. If needs to be reset use {@link RuleForm#resetBeanFields()} directly.
     * */
    public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {

    }

    /**
     * Add empty value. User should have an opportunity not to set value for this field.
     * */
    public Collection getLevels(){
        if(levels == null || levels.size() == 0){
            super.getLevels();
            levels.add(0, new Level());
        }
        return levels;
    }
}
```

The problem is:

1. User goes to /RuleList.do and sees the list of rules. **ruleSearchForm** used as a bean for transferring search params to /RulesList.do action. Initially tihs bean is empty, only getLevels() returns "empty value" + list of levels got from superclass method.
2. User goes to /CreateRule.do, **ruleForm** is used for collecting user input. **levels** property  is used in selectbox. And I get there list of levels + empty row. This empty row is not added in RuleForm (named ruleForm). It's added it subclass of RuleForm.  Why does super class ActionForm bean with NO static fields, with other name gets values from it's sublass instance???
3. If users saves Rule and has been redirected to /RuleList.do, the he sees populated (i.e. filled) search form ("ruleSearchForm") with values from "ruleForm".

What does it mean? Please help, I don't understand this mess of data beetween ActionForm Beans

UPD:
Now, I've changed inheritance of FormAction beans. I've introduced BaseFormBean. This BaseFormBean got two children: RuleForm and RuleSearchForm. 
It didn't help. Still attributes from one bean are moved to another.

*My jsp code:*
**CreateUpdateRule.jsp:**

```
<html:form action="/RuleSave.do">
<html:hidden property="crid"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><bean:message key="rule.levelId"/></td>
        <td><html:select property="levelId">
                <html:optionsCollection  property="levels" value="clid" label="name" />
            </html:select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><bean:message key="rule.timeStart"/></td>
        <td><html:text property="timeStartStr"/></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td><bean:message key="rule.timeEnd"/></td>
        <td><html:text property="timeEndStr"/></td>
    </tr>   

    <tr>
        <td>
            <html:submit styleClass="wpsButtonText"><bean:message key="application.submit"/></html:submit>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" onclick="cancelOperation()" class="wpsButtonText" value="<bean:message key="application.cancel"/>" />
            <html:link styleClass="cancelLink" page="/RuleList.do"></html:link>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table
</html:form>
```

**my RuleList.jsp:**

```
<html:form action="/CritRuleList.do" >
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td><bean:message key="rule.levelId"/></td>
        <td><html:select property=levelId">
                <html:optionsCollection  property="levels" value="clid" label="name" />
            </html:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td><bean:message key="rule.timeStart"/></td>
        <td><html:text property="timeStartStr" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td><bean:message key="rule.timeEnd"/></td>
        <td><html:text property="timeEndStr" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td colspan="2">
            <html:submit styleClass="wpsButtonText"><bean:message key="application.search"/></html:submit>
            <input type="button" onclick="cancelOperation(this)" class="wpsButtonText" value="<bean:message key="critrule.searchClear"/>" />
            <html:link styleClass="cancelLink" page="/RuleResetSearchFilter.do"></html:link>
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>    
</html:form>
```

Comment: Can you also show the relevant parts of the jsp, ie the forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds very strange that a subclass method would be called in the case you've described. To find out why it's happening, you need to debug your code - put a breakpoint inside the if construct of the `RuleSearchForm.getLevels()` method and see if it is really called (and where did the call originate from).

Other than that, you could try to move the populating logic of levels away from the form(s) altogether, and instead do it in the action. So, in the RuleCreate action you would do something like this:

```
List levels = DAOClass.getLevels();
Collections.reverse(levels);
request.setAttribute("levels", levels);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is really hard to follow, and you still left out or changed some mappings (RuleCreate or CreateRule). My guess would be that you have a misunderstanding in which form declaration is used to populate the fields and the options collection. When you create a form like this

```
<html:form action="/RuleSave.do">
```

The values for the select box are taken from the form bean associated with the RuleSave action in your struts-config, not from the form of the action that forwarded to this jsp.

From http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#form:

> Renders an HTML  element ... The form bean is located, and created if necessary, based on the form bean specification for the associated ActionMapping.

Answer (score 0):

The [roblem has been resolved.
1. As Tommi said, I've inspected DAO code. DAO returns list of beans kept in static private field.

```
/**
     * Add empty value. User should have an opportunity not to set value for this field.
     * */
    public Collection getLevels(){
        if(levels == null || levels.size() == 0){
            super.getLevels();
            levels.add(0, new Level());
        }
        return levels;
    }
```

So each time I add empty bean I do change that static list of objects. Terrible bug.

1. Params transferring. I've created struts1 app for WebSphere Portal. Portal doesn't have redirect, because I work with portlets, not with pages. That is why request parameters live in request unlit last jsp page is rendered. It has been also solved.

Comment: You should accept this answer to indicate that the problem has been solved.